# I have a trouble with ExoPlayer. I use one to streaming a radio station

Tags: android, exoplayer2.x

When streaming radio station, stream is stoping and playing again after some delay. And this issue reproduced with bluetooth headset.

```
2020-06-29 12:59:02.577 6159-6645/com.example.player E/AudioTrack: start(): 0x931f7000, mState = 1
2020-06-29 12:59:02.584 6159-6159/com.example.player D/MediaService: onPlayerStateChanged: playWhenReady - true; playbackState - 3
2020-06-29 12:59:02.625 6159-6645/com.example.player D/AudioTrack: correcting timestamp time for pause, currentTimeNanos: 177361604116546 < limitNs: 177364334867316 < mStartNs: 177364574867316
2020-06-29 12:59:02.625 6159-6645/com.example.player W/AudioTrack: retrograde timestamp time corrected, 177364334867316 < 177364578496700
2020-06-29 12:59:02.635 6159-6645/com.example.player D/AudioTrack: correcting timestamp time for pause, currentTimeNanos: 177361604116546 < limitNs: 177364334867316 < mStartNs: 177364574867316
2020-06-29 12:59:02.635 6159-6645/com.example.player W/AudioTrack: retrograde timestamp time corrected, 177364334867316 < 177364578496700
2020-06-29 13:01:58.234 6159-6645/com.example.player D/AudioTrack: pause(): 0x931f7000, mState = 0
2020-06-29 13:01:58.239 6159-6159/com.example.player D/MediaService: onPlayerStateChanged: playWhenReady - true; playbackState - 2
2020-06-29 13:02:05.073 6159-6645/com.example.player E/AudioTrack: start(): 0x931f7000, mState = 2
2020-06-29 13:02:05.079 6159-6159/com.example.player D/MediaService: onPlayerStateChanged: playWhenReady - true; playbackState - 3
2020-06-29 13:02:05.122 6159-6645/com.example.player D/AudioTrack: correcting timestamp time for pause, currentTimeNanos: 177540976640019 < limitNs: 177546830466942 < mStartNs: 177547070466942
2020-06-29 13:02:05.122 6159-6645/com.example.player W/AudioTrack: retrograde timestamp time corrected, 177546830466942 < 177547073697634
2020-06-29 13:02:14.816 6159-6645/com.example.player D/AudioTrack: pause(): 0x931f7000, mState = 0
```

I create exoplayer like this

```
exoPlayer = SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(
            this,
            DefaultRenderersFactory(this),
            DefaultTrackSelector(this),
            DefaultLoadControl(),
            bandwidthMeter,
            Looper.getMainLooper(),
            AnalyticsCollector(Clock.DEFAULT),
            true,
            Clock.DEFAULT
        ).build()
```

Then

```
exoPlayer.playWhenReady = true
prepareExoPlayer()
setSessionState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING)
...
private fun prepareExoPlayer() {
    val mediaSource = buildMediaSource()
    exoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource)
}
private fun buildMediaSource(): MediaSource {
    val dataSourceFactory = DefaultDataSourceFactory(
        this,
        Util.getUserAgent(baseContext, getString(R.string.app_name)),
        bandwidthMeter
    )
    var url = currentStation.middleStream
    return ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(Uri.parse(url))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use ExoPlayer to play audio available via HTTP, try to create specific version of the factory, e.g.:

```kotlin
val dataSourceFactory = DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(
    Util.getUserAgent(baseContext, getString(R.string.app_name))
)
```